# Issue creating a list view button in Lead Object which will open new task form

Tags: apex, trigger, javascript, list-view

Issue while creating a list view button in Lead Object which will open new task form based lead source is equal to web.
Please find the script below.

```
    {!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/29.0/connection.js")}
    {!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/29.0/apex.js")} 
    var url =parent.location.href; 
    var recorid = {!GETRECORDIDS($ObjectType.Lead)};
    var updateRecords = []; 
    if(recorid.length > 0){  
        var strRecIdList = '';  
       for(var i=0; i < recorid.length; i++){  
         strRecIdList += "'" + recorid[i] + "',";  
       } 

    strRecIdList = strRecIdList.substring(0, strRecIdList.length-1);  
    var queryResult =sforce.connection.query("Select id,LeadSource from Lead
    where Id(" + strRecIdList + ")");  
    }

    if (records[0] == null){    
       alert("Please select at least one record to update."); 
    } elseif(queryResult.records[a].Leadsource=='web'){     
      for(var a=0; a<records.length; a++) { {
        window.open("http://www.w3schools.com");    }

     } } else {     parent.location.href = url;  }
```

Comment: what's the issue you are facing when you use this ?

Comment: Onclicking the button it shows unexpected {

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you missed 'IN' in your SOQL query.

```
var queryResult =sforce.connection.query("Select id,LeadSource from Lead
    where Id IN (" + strRecIdList + ")");
```